# Scala implicit typeclass precedence in companion objects

Tags: scala, implicit, companion-object

```
trait Eq[-A] {
  def eq(a: A, b: A): Boolean
}
object Eq {
  implicit object IntEq extends Eq[Int] {
    def eq(a: Int, b: Int) = a == b
  }
}

trait Supertrait[+A]
object Supertrait {
  implicit def Eq[A: Eq]: Eq[Supertrait[A]] = ???
}

trait Subtrait[+A] extends Supertrait[A]
object Subtrait {
  implicit def Eq[A: Eq]: Eq[Subtrait[A]] = ???
}

def f[A](x: Subtrait[A])(implicit ev: Eq[Subtrait[A]]) = ???

f(new Subtrait[Int] {})
```

When compiling this code, the following error occurs:

```
Error:(32, 4) ambiguous implicit values:
 both method Eq in object Supertrait of type [A](implicit evidence$1: Eq[A])Eq[Supertrait[A]]
 and method Eq in object Subtrait of type [A](implicit evidence$2: Eq[A])Eq[Subtrait[A]]
match expected type Eq[Subtrait[Int]]
  f(new Subtrait[Int] {})
   ^
```

Why doesn't the `implicit def` in the `Subtrait` companion object has higher precedence than the one in `Supertrait`?

I'd like that `implicit def`s in the companion object of subtraits have higher precedence than those in supertraits.

#### UPDATE

The `LowPriorityImplicits` trick does not work either. See [Enforcing precedence in implicit instances in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996916/enforcing-precedence-in-implicit-instances-in-scala).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code violates the **Non-Ambiguity Rule** for implicits.

From *Programming in Scala*, 1st edition:

> Non-Ambiguity Rule: An implicit conversion is only inserted if there
>   is no other possible conversion to insert. If the compiler has two
>   options to fix x + y, say using either convert1(x) + y or convert2(x)
>   + y, then it will report an error and refuse to choose between them. It would be possible to define some kind of "best match" rule that
>   prefers some conversions over others. However, such choices lead to
>   really obscure code. Imagine the compiler chooses convert2, but you
>   are new to the file and are only aware of convert1—you could spend a
>   lot of time thinking a different conversion had been applied!

The complete text can be found [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html).

Comment: I know this, but I want to define some precedence relations over these implicit typeclasses.