# Enforcing precedence in implicit instances in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

This is a follow-up on the question [Scala implicit typeclass precedence in companion objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928125/scala-implicit-typeclass-precedence-in-companion-objects).

Suppose that I have two traits, `Trait2 extends Trait1`. Each trait has a specific typeclass instance of `Eq`. I'd like to let the precedence of the typeclass instance of `Trait2` to be higher than tha of `Trait1`. However, the code below (the `LowPriorityImplicits` trick) does not work.

```
trait Eq[-A] {
  def eq(a: A, b: A): Boolean
}

object Eq {
  implicit object IntEq extends Eq[Int] {
    def eq(a: Int, b: Int) = a == b
  }
}

trait Trait1[+A]
trait Trait2[+A] extends Trait1[A]

object Implicits extends LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def Eq2[T: Eq]: Eq[Trait2[T]] = ???
}

trait LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def Eq1[T: Eq]: Eq[Trait1[T]] = ???
}

object Test2 extends App {

  def f[T: Eq](x: T) = ???
  import Implicits._

  val t1 = new Trait1[Int] {}
  val t2 = new Trait2[Int] {}

  f(t2) // COMPILATION ERROR!

}
```

The following compilation error is thrown:

```
Error:(33, 4) ambiguous implicit values:
 both method Eq1 in trait LowPriorityImplicits of type [T](implicit evidence$2: Eq[T])Eq[Trait1[T]]
 and method Eq2 in object Implicits of type [T](implicit evidence$1: Eq[T])Eq[Trait2[T]]
 match expected type Eq[Trait2[Int]]
  f(t2)
   ^
```

How can I enforce the precedence relation of the typeclass instances?

Answer (score 1):

Variance in type parameters doesn't play well with Scala's encoding of type classes. If you want it to compile, simply try this.

```
trait Eq[A] {
  def eq(a: A, b: A): Boolean
}

object Eq {
  implicit object IntEq extends Eq[Int] {
    def eq(a: Int, b: Int) = a == b
  }
}

trait Trait1[A]
trait Trait2[A] extends Trait1[A]

object Implicits extends LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def Eq2[T: Eq]: Eq[Trait2[T]] = ???
}

trait LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def Eq1[T: Eq]: Eq[Trait1[T]] = ???
}

object Test2 extends App {

  def f[T: Eq](x: T) = ???
  import Implicits._

  val t1 = new Trait1[Int] {}
  val t2 = new Trait2[Int] {}

  f(t2) // COMPILATION ERROR!

}
```

If you do want `Eq[Trait2[A]]` to behave like a sub-type of `Eq[Trait1[A]]`, you might be able to use implicit conversions as a workaround.